# How can I make this progress bar with just CSS?

Tags: html, css

Can I make the progress bar below by using CSS only, that is, without using any images? In the second case, one can round the green corners on the left side of the div and not round them on the right side. However, is there a solution for the first and third case without resorting to an external image?

Note, that there should be a smooth transition from the bar being completely empty to being completely green.

[image]

Comment: [This](http://mlicato.tumblr.com/post/11959383748) can be done with CSS only. You think yours can?

Comment: You mean with no images? As CSS does allow use of images...

Comment: @mrtsherman I clarified. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Konerak you are right, it probably should go. Maybe I should have said "elegantly" or an easy solution. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Well 500 rep bounty is a bit much.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Css Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/) has a good article showing how you would achieve this.

[Example](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ProgressBars/)

Re: Comment
Looks pretty close to me
*Notice I have changed the widths of the span elements.*
[image]

***LAST UPDATE***
OP wanted it to *look more like his example*

Change the following ***two*** lines of CSS in the demo

```
.meter {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #555555;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 60px 0 20px;
    overflow: hidden; /* remove padding and add me */
    position: relative;
}
.meter > span {
    background-color: #2BC253;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #2BC253 37%, #54F054 69%);
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px; /* change me */
    box-shadow: 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

[image]

Comment: That site is awesome... click around for a few minutes if you have the time.

Comment: @rlemon the css tricks example does not do the case 1 and case 3.

Comment: @rlemon try setting the width of the progressbar indicator to 100% or something very small and you see what I mean.

Comment: to fix this would require dabbling with the css a bit.. but personally i don't think it looks any worse..

Comment: @rlemon the css tricks example already has slightly rounded edges on the right of the progressbar indicator. Also, the bar in the back is much larger than in my case, where they have the same sizes. I don't think there is an easy fix by dabbling in the css, or at least I haven't found one. That's why I asked the geniuses here :)

Comment: @rlemon thanks! marked the other as correct because he was first. Yours is really interesting for other reasons though.

Answer (score 9):

If you put the green bar inside the grey container and set `overflow: hidden` on the grey container then the green bar will be clipped when you give the container rounded corners.

Comment: I was trying to build this, before I saw all these answers / comments and it seems not to work.

Comment: You're right, works for every browser, except Opera. I'm the 1%... And yeah, saw your fiddle, seems to break when using 1%

Comment: I like Opera too. Maybe I can ask one of devs why it breaks. Had a similar thing not too long ago where Opera was different than the others.

Answer (score 1):

To see it in action in the fiddle, toggle the checkbox to kick off the animation.  I've set it to 3 seconds.  Will work in all modern browsers and IE10.  If you wind up needing JavaScript to kick off an event, or keep track of the time it should run, just change the CSS width of .progress-color.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdillman/ZqCyu/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Progress Bar</title>
<style>
    .progress-bar {
        margin: 5px;
        width: 500px;
        background-color: #DDD;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid #BBB;
        -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
           -moz-border-radius: 15px;
                border-radius: 15px;
    }
    .progress-color {
        background-color: lime;
        background-size: 40px 40px;
        width: 0%;
        height: 30px;
        -webkit-transition: width 2s ease;
           -moz-transition: width 2s ease;
            -ms-transition: width 2s ease;
             -o-transition: width 2s ease;
                transition: width 2s ease;
        -webkit-animation: bganim 3s linear 2s infinite;
           -moz-animation: bganim 3s linear 2s infinite;
            -ms-animation: bganim 3s linear 2s infinite;
             -o-animation: bganim 3s linear 2s infinite;
                animation: bganim 3s linear 2s infinite;
    }

    :checked + .progress-bar .progress-color{
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Install" /> Start Installation:
    <div class="progress-bar">
        <div class="progress-color"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bar {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: rgba(231, 56, 39, 0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress {
  width: 96%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #e73827;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
 <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Explain how this code will solve the problem in question, instead of giving code only answer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to use javascript or images only possible way i can think of is using css3 border radius style. But the problem is old browsers doesn't support for css3

example:

```
border-radius: 5px 10px 5px 10px
```

using above style you can round what ever the corner you like individually.

for more details follow this [link](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment roshnan. I will assume the user has a modern browser in my case. However, the border-radius only helps me in the case 2. In cases 1 and 3 I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

this a simple, smooth, and bootifull loader css3

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GilbertOOl/t5qAu/)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1");</script>

<style>
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aldrich);

body{background:#333;}
.progressbar{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:560px;
    height:20px;
    padding:10px 20px;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    border-radius:16px;
    margin:40px auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px -4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4),0px -3px 3px -3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25),inset 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px -4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4),0px -3px 3px -3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25),inset 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.progressbar:before{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    content:"";
    width:558px;
    height:18px;
    top:10px;
    left:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    border-radius:20px;
    background:#222;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.bar {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    width:0px;
    height:16px;
    top:12px;
    left:22px;
    background: rgb(126,234,25);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(126,234,25,1) 0%, rgba(83,173,0,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(126,234,25,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(83,173,0,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(126,234,25,1) 0%,rgba(83,173,0,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(126,234,25,1) 0%,rgba(83,173,0,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(126,234,25,1) 0%,rgba(83,173,0,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(126,234,25,1) 0%,rgba(83,173,0,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7eea19', endColorstr='#53ad00',GradientType=0 );
    -webkit-border-radius:16px;
    border-radius:16px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(126, 234, 25, 1),inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45),inset 1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25),inset -1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(126, 234, 25, 1),inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45),inset 1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25),inset -1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    overflow:hidden;
}
.bar.color2 {
    background: rgb(229,195,25);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(229,195,25,1) 0%, rgba(168,140,0,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(229,195,25,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(168,140,0,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(229,195,25,1) 0%,rgba(168,140,0,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(229,195,25,1) 0%,rgba(168,140,0,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(229,195,25,1) 0%,rgba(168,140,0,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(229,195,25,1) 0%,rgba(168,140,0,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e5c319', endColorstr='#a88c00',GradientType=0 );
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(229, 195, 25, 1),inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45),inset 1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25),inset -1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(229, 195, 25, 1),inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45),inset 1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25),inset -1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}
.bar.color3 {
    background: rgb(232,25,87);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(232,25,87,1) 0%, rgba(170,0,51,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(232,25,87,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(170,0,51,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(232,25,87,1) 0%,rgba(170,0,51,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(232,25,87,1) 0%,rgba(170,0,51,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(232,25,87,1) 0%,rgba(170,0,51,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(232,25,87,1) 0%,rgba(170,0,51,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e81957', endColorstr='#aa0033',GradientType=0 );
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(232, 25, 87, 1),inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45),inset 1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25),inset -1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(232, 25, 87, 1),inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45),inset 1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25),inset -1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}
.bar.color4 {
    background: rgb(24,109,226);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(24,109,226,1) 0%, rgba(0,69,165,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(24,109,226,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,69,165,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(24,109,226,1) 0%,rgba(0,69,165,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(24,109,226,1) 0%,rgba(0,69,165,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(24,109,226,1) 0%,rgba(0,69,165,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(24,109,226,1) 0%,rgba(0,69,165,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#186de2', endColorstr='#0045a5',GradientType=0 );
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(24, 109, 226, 1),inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45),inset 1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25),inset -1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(24, 109, 226, 1),inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45),inset 1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25),inset -1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}
.bar:before {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    content:"";
    width:606px;
    height:150%;
    top:-25%;
    left:-25px;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,0.35) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.01) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 51%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.35)), color-stop(50%,rgba(255,255,255,0.01)), color-stop(51%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)));
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,0.35) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.01) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,0.35) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.01) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,0.35) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.01) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(255,255,255,0.35) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.01) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#59ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 );
}
.bar:after {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    content:"";
    width:64px;
    height:16px;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 16px 16px 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 16px 16px 0px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 98%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(98%,rgba(255,255,255,0.6)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 98%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 98%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 98%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 98%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 );
}
.bar span {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:64px;
    -webkit-border-radius:16px;
    border-radius:16px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:url("data:image/png;base64,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") 0 0;
    -webkit-animation: sparkle 1500ms linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: sparkle 1500ms linear infinite;
    -o-animation: sparkle 1500ms linear infinite;
    animation: sparkle 1500ms linear infinite;
    opacity:0.2;
}
.label {
    font-family: 'Aldrich', sans-serif;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    width:40px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    top:38px;
    left:0px;
    background: rgb(76,76,76);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%, rgba(38,38,38,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(76,76,76,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(38,38,38,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(38,38,38,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(38,38,38,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(38,38,38,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(38,38,38,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#262626',GradientType=0 );
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #000000,0px 1px 1px #000000;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#000000, offx=0, offy=-1);
}
.label span {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    width:12px;
    height:9px;
    top:-9px;
    left:14px;
    background:transparent;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.label span:before {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    content:"";
    width:8px;
    height:8px;
    top:4px;
    left:2px;
    border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background: rgb(86,86,86);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(86,86,86,1) 0%, rgba(76,76,76,1) 50%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(86,86,86,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(76,76,76,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(86,86,86,1) 0%,rgba(76,76,76,1) 50%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(86,86,86,1) 0%,rgba(76,76,76,1) 50%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(86,86,86,1) 0%,rgba(76,76,76,1) 50%);
    background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(86,86,86,1) 0%,rgba(76,76,76,1) 50%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#565656', endColorstr='#4c4c4c',GradientType=1 );
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -1px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0px -1px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}
@-webkit-keyframes sparkle {
    from {background-position: 0 0;}
    to {background-position: 0 -64px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes sparkle {
    from {background-position: 0 0;}
    to {background-position: 0 -64px;}
}
@-o-keyframes sparkle {
    from {background-position: 0 0;}
    to {background-position: 0 -64px;}
}
@keyframes sparkle {
    from {background-position: 0 0;}
    to {background-position: 0 -64px;}
}
</style>

<script language="javascript">
$(function() {

    $('.progressbar').each(function(){
        var t = $(this),
            dataperc = t.attr('data-perc'),
            barperc = Math.round(dataperc*5.56);
        t.find('.bar').animate({width:barperc}, dataperc*25);
        t.find('.label').append('<div class="perc"></div>');

        function perc() {
            var length = t.find('.bar').css('width'),
                perc = Math.round(parseInt(length)/5.56),
                labelpos = (parseInt(length)-2);
            t.find('.label').css('left', labelpos);
            t.find('.perc').text(perc+'%');
        }
        perc();
        setInterval(perc, 0); 
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="progressbar" data-perc="100">
    <div class="bar"><span></span></div>
    <div class="label"><span></span></div>
</div>
<div class="progressbar" data-perc="75">
    <div class="bar color2"><span></span></div>
    <div class="label"><span></span></div>
</div>
<div class="progressbar" data-perc="50">
    <div class="bar color3"><span></span></div>
    <div class="label"><span></span></div>
</div>
<div class="progressbar" data-perc="25">
    <div class="bar color4"><span></span></div>
    <div class="label"><span></span></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```